# Writing only first line of the command output in Windows cmd to a file

Tags: windows, script, vbscript

I want to modify the command `somecommand >> file1.txt`
in a way that **only the first line of the command output** be saved to the file.

How is it possible, what script is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited** simplified, same idea, less code

```
somecommand | cmd /q /v:on /c "set/p .=&echo(!.!" >> file1.txt
```

**edited** to adapt to comments. To include in a vbs file

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /q /c ""somecommand | cmd /q /v:on /c ""set/p .=&echo(!.!"" >> file1.txt "" ",0
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I should put this command in a .VBS file?

Comment: @Campiador, answer updated.

Comment: thanks, this is my command: aapt dump badging box.apk, should I just put it in thecommand without any change?

Comment: especially, the part with box.apk, I want to use a File Object

Comment: @Campiador, `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /q /c "" aapt dump badging """+oAPKFile.Path+""" | cmd /q /v:on /c ""set/p .=&echo(!.!"" >> file1.txt "" ",0`

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution is concise and correct.

Answer (score 2):

First write all the output in the file:

```
somecommand > file2.txt
```

After that save only the first row in the file:

```
set /p firstline=<file2.txt
echo %firstline% > file1.txt
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, actually I may add this to an existing file with >>, so if I do what you told I will miss all the previous reports.

Comment: Thist is not problem at all, just use a temporary file2.txt - I have edited. The point is, the first row of the output is in the variable %firstline% , that is what you need to use with >>

Comment: this is my command: aapt dump badging god.apk > file2.txt do you know how I should modify it in order to put it in .vbs script?

Comment: Try something like WshShell.Run("aapt dump badging god.apk > file2.txt", 0, true);